# Indented math definition?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

How can I format a math equation for a graph definition so that it has an intended "body" as in the following example?

```
graph2 = (
    {c1, c2, ..., c8},
    {e1, e2, ..., e12}
)
```

I tried using the AMS `align*` environment, but the alignment of the last bracket is wrong, somehow not left-aligned.

```
\begin{align*}
graph2 & =(\\
   & \left\{ c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_8 \right\},\\
   & \left\{ e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_{12} \right\},\\
)
\end{align*}
```

You can see the problem in this rendering:

[image: misaligned align* equation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a job for `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\graph}[3]{% #1 = graph name, #2 = nodes, #3 = edges
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  #1 = ( \\
  \qquad \{ #2 \}, \\
  \qquad \{ #3 \}, \\
  )
  \end{array}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\graph{\mathit{graph}2}{c_1,c_2,\dots,c_8}{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_{12}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]